# Formal statistical test for whether a process is a white noise

Tags: time-series, white-noise

Is there a formal statistical test to test if process is a white noise?

Comment: against what alternative ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In time-series analysis usually [Ljung-Box test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung-Box_test) is used. Note though that it tests the correlations. If the correlations are zero, but variance varies, then the process is not white noise, but Ljung-Box test will fail to reject the null-hypothesis. Here is an example in R:

```
> Box.test(c(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,0,10)),type="Ljung-Box")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  c(rnorm(100, 0, 1), rnorm(100, 0, 10)) 
X-squared = 0.4771, df = 1, p-value = 0.4898
```

Here is the plot of the process:
[image]

Here is more discussion [about this test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/how-many-lags-to-use-in-the-ljung-box-test-of-a-time-series).

Comment: Ouliers in the error series will "deflate the ACF" thus yielding an ALICE IN WINDERKlAND effect. All ACF's are subject to this thus one must ensure no anomalies

Answer (score 0):

The R library hwwntest (Haar Wavelet White Noise test) seems to work pretty well.  It offers a number of functions.  It does require the amount of data to be a power of 2.

[hywavwn.test()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hwwntest/index.html) seems to work the best for me.

```
> hywavwn.test(rnorm(128, 0, 1))

    Hybrid Wavelet Test of White Noise

data:  
p-value = 0.542

> hywavwn.test(rnorm(128, 0, 10))

    Hybrid Wavelet Test of White Noise

data:  
p-value = 1
```