# Conclusion about an auto-correlation plot

Tags: econometrics, autocorrelation

I have a dataseries with the following auto-correlation function. What would you conclude from this? I mean, if it is an ARIMA (a,b,c), what are the values of a, b and c? I think it is ARIMA (0,0,0), hence pure white noise.[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the partial auto correlation function? you need to look at that before you make any conclusions about the process you are looking at.

Comment: if you think its white noise you would have to look at the Q-statistic

Comment: I think it was discussed a couple of times before, for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/formal-statistical-test-for-whether-a-process-is-a-white-noise