# Test for independence of random variables

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, residuals, autoregressive

I have a time series of data (about 300-750 elements, depending on the sample) and a model that has some random residues. I used the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to make sure that the normality hypothesis can't be rejected, so I assume that the residuals are normally distributed. But now I guess I should test if they are independent of each other - so that there is no autoregression? Which test should I use (preferably one that is easily implementable in java)?

Answer (score 2):

You could try  Runs test for randomness. I am not familiar with Java functions. I got a link related to runs test that may useful to you. [JAVA NPST](http://sci2s.ugr.es/software/javanpst/tests.php).  Apart from this you could do durbin-watson test or Ljung-Box portmanteau test. Most important is the visual check of time series plot ( I guess you have done this already).

Comment: If you go with Ljung-Box, which is easy to program, you might want to check out this [question and answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/how-many-lags-to-use-in-the-ljung-box-test-of-a-time-series).

Comment: Hi, which flavor of the runs test? Calculating the runs when the value increases and decreases?

Comment: You need to check both. The rejection rule is $R \leq C_1$ or $R \geq C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are critical values obtained from table (or from normal distribution for large sample)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a permutation test.  Compute a measure of autocorrelation, then randomly permute the values and recompute the same measure of autocorrelation.  Do the permute and recompute step a bunch of times (like 2,000 overall) and compare the value for the original ordering to the permuted values to do the test.