# Ljung Box test for residuals of constrained ARIMAX(2,1,0) model

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, residuals, autoregressive

I have this ARIMA(2,1,0) model with one exogenous variable: $$\Delta y_t=c+\phi_2 \Delta y_{t-2}+\beta_x x_t+\varepsilon_t$$

I want to run [Ljung Box test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) of residual autocorrelation with test statistic:

$$Q = n\left(n+2\right)\sum_{k=1}^h\frac{\hat{\rho}^2_k}{n-k}$$

Suppose, I already know what lags $h$ to use. What should be the degrees of freedom here?

Comment: Isn't the degree of freedom set as h − p − q? So h - 2 - 0 ?

Comment: I don't think you should use the Ljung-Box test in the first place. See [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/testing-for-autocorrelation-ljung-box-versus-breusch-godfrey).

Answer (score 0):

It is important to emphasize that this test is applied to the residual of the fitted model, **NOT THE ORIGINAL SEQUENCE OF DATA.**

So we are testing the null: Residuals from the ARIMA model have no auto correlation.

**Here is the problem:** the number of lags used in the ARIMA model is not *h*.

*h* has to be sufficiently large to capture any correlations. Some textbooks recommend  h to be at least 10 for non-seasonal data (check http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/).

Therefore if *h=10*:

Degrees of freedom: *h-p-q*
In your case: *10 - 2 – 0=8*

Comment: The answer to the question comes only in the last line and is not detailed at all (you just state a fact). Consider editing to answer the *actual* question and provide some motivation for the answer.