# Difference between Ljung Box and McLeod Li Test?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, self-study, autocorrelation

I'm a little confused. What is the difference between the Ljung-Box test and the McLeod-Li test?

The Ljung-Box test is a test for linearity in the mean and the McLeod-Li is a test for nonlinearity on the mean and/or in variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ljung-Box test is a test for autocorrelation in either raw data or model residuals. The test is described quite clearly in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test). I will add that alternatives to Ljung-Box test exist and in some situations are preferred; see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/testing-for-autocorrelation-ljung-box-versus-breusch-godfrey) comparing Ljung-Box test with Breusch-Godfrey test.

McLeod-Li test is a test for autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity in either raw data or residuals from a conditional mean model (but not for residuals from a GARCH model; there Li-Mak test should be used instead).

The similarity between the two tests is that McLeod-Li test takes the form of a Ljung-Box test applied on *squared* raw data or *squared* model residuals. Despite the similarity in their shapes, the purposes of the tests are different, as explained above.

Also, what you state in your second paragraph is incorrect.

> "Li-Mak test should be used instead". I'm doing a Time Series Financial Course and we won't see this test. Is [this/there] a better test?

When applied on standardized residuals from a GARCH model, McLeod-Li test does not have the usual null distribution, thus you do not have a benchmark to compare the test statistic to. Consequently, you cannot obtain a p-value or tell whether the test statistic is above or below a 5% (or whatever %) critical value. Meanwhile, Li-Mak test is especially suited for this situation. See Li, W. K. and Mak, T. K. (1994) ["On the squared residual autocorrelations in non-linear time series with conditional heteroscedasticity](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1994.tb00217.x). *Journal of Time Series Analysis 15,* 627–36.

Comment: Thanks Richards! Interesting your observation: "Li-Mak test should be used instead". Im doing a Time Series Financial Course and we wont see this test. Is  a better test?

Comment: When applied on standardized residuals from a GARCH model, McLeod-Li test does not have the usual null distribution, thus you do not have a benchmark to compare the test statistic to, and consequently you cannot obtain a $p$-value or tell whether the test statistic is above or below a 5% (or whatever %) critical value. Meanwhile, Li-Mak test is especially suited for this situation. See Li, W. K. and Mak, T. K. (1994) *On the squared residual autocorrelations in non-linear time series with conditional heteroscedasticity*. Journal of Time Series Analysis 15, 627–36.