# Autocorrelation in the squared residuals of Multivariate GARCH models

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, matlab, garch

Most papers use the [Hosking (1980)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/portes/versions/3.0/topics/Hosking) to detect whether the multivariate GARCH model used captures all heteroskedasticity effects. However, [Bauwens (2006)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jae.842)(p.101-102) do state shortcomings of it, when applied in this context, but they do also mention that it does provide a useful diagnostic in many situations.

So, I would like to ask you, whether a better test exists (and if it was available in R or Matlab would also be nice).

Comment: From personal experience, I am not so sure most papers use Hosking (1980), but this is just my experience.

Comment: Did you find any better tests?

Comment: No I did not find any better alternative. I hope this among other parameter evaluations will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think Li-Mak [(Li & Mak, 1994)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1994.tb00217.x) (univariate) and Ling-Li [(Ling & Li, 1997)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1994.tb00217.x) (multivariate) tests are suitable candidates for error diagnostics in univariate and multivariate GARCH models, respectively. Unlike some other (popular) tests*, they account for the fact that standardized residuals from GARCH models are not equal to true standardized innovations but are mere estimates thereof and contain estimation errors**. However, I have not investigated their performance empirically nor do I remember studying any references doing that. Nevertheless, there is a paper [(Wong & Ling, 2005)](http://www.math.ust.hk/~maling/paper/Wong-Ling.pdf) investigating some practical aspects of and containing tips on the use of these and other tests; I hope it can be useful.

*The deficiencies of some popular (univariate) tests are analyzed in [Chen (2002)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e75e/0790e9532cc5d6787c4a388c51d2fa34b355.pdf), among other. The deficiencies extend from the univariate to the multivariate case as well, since taking residuals for actual innovations is a problem regardless of the dimension of the time series.
**This problem is characteristic not only to testing residuals of GARCH models, but also those of ARMA models; see the thread ["Testing for autocorrelation: Ljung-Box versus Breusch-Godfrey"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/) for why popular tests fail there.

**References**

- Li, W. K. & Mak, T. K. (1994). [On the squared residual autocorrelations in non-linear time series with conditional heteroscedasticity](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1994.tb00217.x). *Journal of Time Series Analysis* 15, 627–36.
- Ling, S. & Li, W. K. (1997). [Diagnostic checking of nonlinear multivariate time series with multivariate arch errors](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-9892.00061). *Journal of Time Series Analysis* 18, 447–64.
- Wong, H., & Ling, S. (2005). [Mixed portmanteau tests for time‐series models](http://www.math.ust.hk/~maling/paper/Wong-Ling.pdf). *Journal of Time Series Analysis*, 26(4), 569-579.
- Chen, Yi−Ting. (2002). [On the Robustness of Ljung−Box and McLeod−Li Q Tests: A Simulation Study](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e75e/0790e9532cc5d6787c4a388c51d2fa34b355.pdf). *Economics Bulletin, 3*(17), 1−10.

Comment: In Bawens, it says that also the Ling-Li test has problems
("Tse and Tsui (1999) show that there is a loss of information and the test may suffer from a power reduction"), so I was looking for something better. But, still I haven't found any package that has the Ling-Li test in R. Is there any available?

Comment: @GeorgiosStrat, I do not remember any relevant R packages as of now.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway.