# Ljung-Box test to determine white noise of time-series (not residual)

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, white-noise

I know we use Ljung-Box test to determine if the residuals are white noise or not. Can we use same test to determine if the time-series in itself is white - noise? This is to by-pass acf-pacf plotting, as I need to forecast some hundred's of series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. In fact, this is the case for which the Box-Pierce test, and its later refinement, the Ljung-Box test were designed.

The application of the test to residuals - which, from a subject matter point of view, is often the more interesting hypothesis to test as there are not many time series which might conceivably be white noise - in turn is fraught with certain difficulties, which are described for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/testing-for-autocorrelation-ljung-box-versus-breusch-godfrey/148290).

Comment: The [Ljung-Box paper](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/956/ResourceDetails/TestingNormality/LjungBox.pdf) appears to mention the residuals, not the time series itself. Could you please point to a reference which describes how the test applies to a time series?

Comment: I think the paper spells it out - consider how they distinguish between $r_k$ and $\hat r_k$ and note that for the WN null, $\phi(B)=\theta(B)=1$, so that $w_t=a_t$.