# What is the meaning of "lag" in Box.test (Ljung-Box test)

Tags: r, arima, autocorrelation, degrees-of-freedom, lags

I want to conduct the Ljung-Box test on residuals of the ARIMA model with

```
Box.test(e, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf = degrees_of_freedom)
```

where N = 3064, with 8 variables and additional 1 adjustmend from ar(1) in ARIMA model.

But I get weird results

> Box-Ljung test
>
> data:    e
> X-squared = 20.134, df = -3055, p-value = NA

Obviously df and p-value are off and I know it has to do something with the `lag` parameter in Box.test function. But I don't know what this parameter really does nor how to determine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely with `fitdf`, not `lag`. When applying the Ljung-Box test on residuals of an ARMA(p,q) model, `fitdf` should equal $p+q$. The first $p+q$ autocorrelations will be estimated at zero by construction, so you are supposed to adjust the asymptotic distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis for that. This is what `fitdf` does. In combination with `lag`, it facilitates setting the degrees of freedom parameter of the $\chi^2$ asymptotic distribution to `lag`-`fitdf`. What you apparently did instead is set `fitdf` to the length of the series minus your parameter count, which resulted in `lag`-`fitdf` being negative and thus producing nonsense null distribution and no $p$-value.

The degrees-of-freedom correction via `fitdf` would seem to make the test work alright, but apparently it does not, as explained in the thread ["Testing for autocorrelation: Ljung-Box versus Breusch-Godfrey"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004). Thus you should **not** use the Ljung-Box test on residuals of an ARIMA model in the first place; use the Breusch-Godfrey test instead.