# What to do when model fails Ljung-Box test?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation, exponential-smoothing

I have been learning time-series forecasting recently and I am trying to understand the procedure. I would like to find the best model for a daily time series, so far I tried exponential smoothing with `ets` and also ARIMA with `auto.arima`, but when I pass both models to Ljung-Box test, they both fail. I would like to know how I could improve the forecast here since I am relatively new and have many questions as I would like to learn more and dive deeper into this field. For example I am familiar with improving the forecast of linear models with AR models where we apply an ARIMA model on the residuals and improve it. But about `ets` and ARIMA models I am not sure.
Here are the results:

```r
# The forecast for 14 days ahead

auto.arima(ts_d) %>%
  forecast(h = 14) %>%
  autoplot()
```

and also the result of Ljung-Box test:

```r
checkresiduals(auto.arima(ts_d))

    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ARIMA(0,1,2)(2,0,2)[7]
Q* = 16.683, df = 8, p-value = 0.03358

Model df: 6.   Total lags used: 14
```

The result of exponential smoothing model:

```r
ets(ts_d) %>%
  forecast() %>%
  plot()
```

And also the result of Ljung-Box test for exponential smoothing:

```r
checkresiduals(ets(ts_d))

    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ETS(A,N,A)
Q* = 21.076, df = 5, p-value = 0.0007837

Model df: 9.   Total lags used: 14
```

One more thing I don't understand is why I got an error message as follows when I apply a log transformation on my ARIMA model:

> Error in auto.arima(ts_d, lambda = 0) : No suitable ARIMA model found
> In addition: Warning message: The chosen seasonal unit root test
> encountered an error when testing for the first difference. From
> stl(): NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1) 0 seasonal
> differences will be used. Consider using a different unit root test.

Here I also add a reproducible version of my `ts`:

```
structure(c(70, 4, 27, 25, 27, 6, 58, 44, 6, 29, 60, 65, 36, 
36, 43, 0, 0, 22, 48, 19, 38, 58, 0, 20, 28, 90, 30, 28, 42, 
9, 26, 42, 48, 42, 76, 49, 15, 49, 33, 32, 54, 34, 62, 22, 27, 
24, 33, 47, 18, 13, 2, 10, 8, 13, 12, 20, 29, 7, 28, 26, 33, 
36, 51, 114, 9, 42, 57, 75, 30, 41, 15, 28, 49, 62, 30, 37, 85, 
9, 31, 32, 45, 27, 45, 59, 7, 19, 32, 44, 21, 49, 61, 12, 10, 
24, 28, 36, 36, 43, 12, 15, 27, 21, 15, 35, 48, 6, 15, 36, 36, 
36, 24, 28, 6, 30, 43, 18, 60, 32, 43, 14, 33, 37, 27, 30, 79, 
3, 22, 29, 36, 26, 56, 13, 16, 44, 53, 34, 8, 53, 44, 4, 32, 
38, 22, 29, 49, 18, 15, 14, 21, 29, 20, 36, 23, 3, 33, 24, 16, 
45, 11, 34, 9, 14, 21, 23, 21, 39, 22, 3, 13, 6, 15, 18, 31, 
15, 9, 9, 12, 9, 3, 15, 27, 30, 24, 12, 3, 18, 15, 9, 9, 21, 
27, 9, 6, 12, 12, 30, 3, 24, 9), .Tsp = c(1, 29.2857142857143, 
7), class = "ts")
```

Thank you very much in advance for your time and please forgive me if my question seems so basic as I am quite naive in the field but very eager to improve.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No need to format non-code as `code`. Also, see ["Testing for autocorrelation: Ljung-Box versus Breusch-Godfrey"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/testing-for-autocorrelation-ljung-box-versus-breusch-godfrey).

Comment: Also, it does not seem the Ljung-Box test fails. Rather, it seems your models fail the test, and that is a different thing. Consider editing the title to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Hardy, I made the required edits to my question. Do you have any suggestion on who to improve it then? or what should we do next when our model fails such test?

Comment: The latter edit of removing some code formatting was for the worse.  I have fixed that. Regarding exponential smoothing yielding autocorrelated residuals, it depends on how strong the autocorrelation is (magnitude, not only statistical significance). If it is strong, consider using another model or modelling the residuals and adjusting your forecasts accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr. Hardy. I managed to fix this by playing with `p`, `d` and `q` parameters. I would like to ask would it be weird if I could use a model like `Arima(ts_d2, order = c(20, 2, 2), lambda = 0.3)` for example with a `p` of `20` so that all residuals become independent with p-value also greater than 0.05?

Comment: There is the bias-variance trade-off. If you have a complex model like yours, its bias may be low but variance will be high, unless you time series is very long. That will have a negative impact on forecast accuracy. Consider using regularized estimation or setting some coefficients to zero to mitigate that. Consider using `auto.arima` for model selection, as that model selection algorithm is tuned specifically with forecast accuracy in mind.

Comment: Thank you dear Mr. Hardy, I managed to solve the issue. What I actually didn't pay attention was I had more data on this product so my time series is now longer spanning 3 years so I used `auto.arima` to get an `ARIMA(0,1,1)` and my `p.value` is now `0.4505` and `AICc` is around `61.05` with only one lag outside the blue dotted lines in ACF diagram.

Comment: I just have one question: Based on what you mentioned above so with this new `p.value` if we have only one or two lags outside the blue dotted lines, does it mean that our model fitted the data quite well? which one actually defines the situation better? Thank you very much for your time and all of the valuable advice. I am leaning all this material for a month but I plan on going on and try to understand more. It takes time a bit.

Comment: The new model with its diagnostics sounds quite good to me. If the lags that stick out are distant lags (not the first few) and/or they stick out only a little bit, then they are probably harmless. Note that under the null hypothesis of no autocorrelation, on average 1 out of 20 lags would stick out of the confidence bounds by pure chance.

Comment: I understand, Thank you very much for your time and recommendations. I really appreciate it. I would like to learn more about this subject but I am sure I can learn a lot from inspiration people like you on stackexchange :)

Comment: I am terribly sorry again Mr. Hardy, just one more thing. Is it really essential to partition the data to train and test for `Arima` models? Because in this case I didn't do that. However, fore evaluating `Accuracy` it could be.

Comment: I have posted an answer summarizing what we have discussed. This suits the format of Cross Validated better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding exponential smoothing yielding autocorrelated residuals, it depends on how strong the autocorrelation is (magnitude, not only statistical significance). If it is strong, consider using another model or modelling the residuals and adjusting your forecasts accordingly.

> Thank you very much dear Mr. Hardy. I managed to fix this by playing with $p$, $d$ and $q$ parameters. I would like to ask would it be weird if I could use a model like `Arima(ts_d2, order = c(20, 2, 2), lambda = 0.3)` for example with a $p$ of `20` so that all residuals become independent with $p$-value also greater than `0.05`?

There is the bias-variance trade-off. If you have a complex model like yours, its bias may be low but variance will be high, unless you time series is very long. That will have a negative impact on forecast accuracy. Consider using regularized estimation or setting some coefficients to zero to mitigate that. Consider using `auto.arima` for model selection, as that model selection algorithm is tuned specifically with forecast accuracy in mind.

> I used `auto.arima` to get an ARIMA(0,1,1) and my $p$-value is now 0.4505 and AICc is around 61.05 with only one lag outside the blue dotted lines in ACF diagram. <...> Based on what you mentioned above so with this new $p$-value if we have only one or two lags outside the blue dotted lines, does it mean that our model fitted the data quite well? which one actually defines the situation better?

The new model with its diagnostics sounds quite good to me. If the lags that stick out are distant lags (not the first few) and/or they stick out only a little bit, then they are probably harmless. Note that under the null hypothesis of no autocorrelation, on average 1 out of 20 lags would stick out of the confidence bounds by pure chance.

> Is it really essential to partition the data to train and test for ARIMA models? Because in this case I didn't do that.

In a time series setting, this is quite costly, as you generally cannot do leave-one-out or $k$-fold cross validation like you could in a cross section. But for a fair evaluation of predictive performance, splitting the data into training and test subsamples is hard to beat. If you were not doing any model selection, AIC would be a fair estimate of the model's expected loss on new data in terms of $-2n\ \times$ the log-likelihood. But when doing model selection, the selected model suffers from the winner's curse, so the AIC of the winner is overly optimistic. Thus better consider using a test subset to evaluate your model.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Hardy for this valuable points. I got it right in the end. I only have one remaining question. Here I used `auto.arima` with a larger data set and got the desired result but in case the model fails `Ljung-Box` with so many lags sticking out, should we just as you mentioned try to apply different models like `ets` or we could try `Arima` and set `p`, `d` & `q` parameteres manually? Thank you very much in advance again.

Comment: But Something I also noticed, depending the length of `training` and `test` data set, the model may pass or fail the `Ljung-Box` test.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, to an extent it boils down to bias-variance trade-off. If `auto.arima` considered a sufficiently wide range of models, it has done a "conscious" choice to select a simpler model and leave some lags sticking out to reduce variance. If it did not consider a sufficiently large range of models, you may find a model outside `auto.arima`'s range that is better. `ets` contains a somewhat diffferent range of models (though there is some overlap with `auto.arima`), so it would not hurt to consider them, too. Re your last comment: there is sampling variability; need to live with it...

Comment: Thanks indeed for taking your time to answer my questions. I know you are so busy, so there is no rush just whenever it was possible. Yes I will have to learn more about bias-variance trade-off. I will try `ets`  or `stlf` too, is it correct that `ets`/`stlf`  functions choose the best fit? I mean do I need to set for example additive or multiplicative type of seasonality myself?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, I think `ets` does that for you. For `stlf`, check out the help files / function description.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I will post some other questions later on :)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, no problem. Consider doing that in new threads.

Comment: Yes that was what I intended to do. Posting new questions in new threads. Thanks indeed. Now that I learned a bit more about these stuff I can be more specific.