# How to define degree of freedom for Ljung Box text?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, arima, autocorrelation, residuals, degrees-of-freedom

I am using `Ljung-box` test after fitting an `ARIMA` model to a time series to investigate whether residuals do look like white noise or not. For this purpose I need to define the degree of freedom in the `ljung_box` function in `R`. I am not sure how we extract the number of parameters, is the sum of `p`, `q` and the Seasonal `P` & `Q` in case we have a seasonal `ARIMA` model?
As an example imagine we have a regression model with `ARIMA` errors like this:

```r
fit <- vic_elec_daily %>%
  model(ARIMA(Demand ~ Temperature + I(Temperature^2) + 
    (Day_Type == "Weekday")))
```

Resulting in:

```r
fit

# A mable: 1 x 1
  `ARIMA(Demand ~ Temperature + I(Temperature^2) + 
    (Day_Type == \n    "Weekday"))`
                                                                           <model>
1                                            <LM w/ ARIMA(2,1,2)(2,0,0)[7] errors>
```

The degree of the freedom specified by the Dr. Hyndman is 9 in this [case](https://otexts.com/fpp3/forecasting.html) but I am not sure how one should do it.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: See ["Testing for autocorrelation: Ljung-Box versus Breusch-Godfrey"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004) to learn that Ljung-Box test is not suited for residuals from an ARMA model – despite numerous papers and books that use it there.

Comment: Thank you dear Richard for the shared link. I will take a closer look on that, but still I only want to know how I can specify the degree of freedom.

Comment: That post contains some guidance on that, too, although it is moot given that the Ljung-Box test produces rubbish results when applied on residuals from an ARMA model...

Comment: Thanks Richard I will check it out then. I read in a post that the degree of freedom for an arima model in Ljung box test should be `m - p - q`  with `m` being the seasonal period in my case is 7. However, we also have seasonal `P` and `Q` so I am a bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\hat \rho = [\hat \rho_1 \ \dots \ \hat \rho_p]'$ be the estimated correlation coefficients for $p$ lags. Under the null of no correlation it holds that $\hat \rho \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_p)$, where $I_p$ is the $p \times p$ identity matrix (proof needed). The Ljung-Box test (similar to the Box-Pierce test) uses the statistic $\hat \rho ' \hat \rho \sim \chi^2_p$, which is chi-squared distributed with $p$ degrees of freedom. Hence the degrees of freedom of a Ljung-Box test refers to the degrees of freedom of the $\chi^2$ distribution, which refers to the number of lags tested for autocorrelation.

Comment: This holds for raw data but not for residuals from an ARMA model. Thus the answer may be misleading.

Comment: I second the comment by @RichardHardy. After parameter estimation the degrees of freedom must be reduced accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still I haven't understood clearly how I can discern the degree of freedom when we have a model as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

the degree of freedom should be the number of parameter estimates. As stated in this book - "To be sure, we use a Ljung-Box test, being careful to set the degrees of freedom to match the number of parameters in the model." (see section 9.9 here https://otexts.com/fpp3/seasonal-arima.html). So, for a non-seasonal ARIMA model dof will be p+q. For a seasonal ARIMA model, the dof should p+q+P+Q. Hope this helps.