Degrees of freedom for Ljung-Box test
I have two questions regarding the degrees of freedom for the Ljung-Box test on residuals in case of different AR(p) models:
In case of a model with non-consecutive lags: As I understand it, one has to subtract the number of estimated parameters (k) from the number of lags (l) to be tested to get the right degrees of freedom. Usually, k equals p. Now, for example, if I have an AR(4) model with only 2 AR coefficients instead of 4, I only estimate 2 parameters. Which value should I take? 4 or 2?
In case of a model with structural break: If there is a structural break, a model can be improved by, for example, binary interaction terms. These model parameters would then have to be estimated. Would they also be included in the value k?

It is questionable whether the Ljung-Box tests is appropriate for residuals of AR models; the Breusch-Godfrey test may be a good substitute: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004
