# Ljung-Box statistic doesn't match to ACF of ARIMAX

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, diagnostic

I'm afraid I basically missunderstand something in the Ljung-Box-Pierce test. 
I estimate an ARMAX model with $y$ as seasonal response variable with periodicity in lag 144, and ARMA(3,1) process for modeling the errors, Fourier series in the `xreg` argument for modeling seasonality (because of long length and multiple wiggly seasonality) and an exogenous variable $x$. The model works almost great for forecast and a $t$-test proves $x$ as significant influence on $y$ as it should be on preliminary considerations.

The model is estimated with `R` and the package `forecast` in this way:

```
 Freg = forecast::fourier(y, K=45)  # optimal K estimated with gcv 
 Exo = cbind(Freg, x)
 fit <- Arima(y[1:2000], order=c(3,0,1), xreg=Exo[1:2000,])
```

[image]

You see, the forecast (blue lines with grey confidence interval) isn't perfect, but it is a good match in general with estimating the model with $N = 2000$ observations and forecasting $6000$ (red line original time series).

Now model diagnostics:

A test for white-noise by Bartlett with $H_{0} = \text{"residuals are white-noise"}$ passed with a $p$-value of 0.939.

The graphics for serial correlations look OK in my mind (maybe except the PACF in very high lags), as you can see in the graphic below.

[image]

Now I want to prove the good impression of a well-predicting model with a Ljung-Box-Pierce test.

The test is based on the statistic

$$
Q = N(N+2) \sum_{t=1}^{h} \frac{1}{N-t} \cdot \tilde{\rho}_{t}^{2} 
$$

where $N$ is the number of observations (number of residuals here), $h$ is the test lag, $\tilde{\rho}_{t}^{2}$ the correlation of observations (residuals) in lag $t$.

The $Q$ statistic follows a $\chi^2$ distribution with $h - 4$ degrees of freedom. The $4$ in $h-4$ comes from the estimation of the ARMA parameters. Because of the long length seasonality I want to check the $p$-values of the Ljung-Box-Pierce for the lags 5 to 288 as Rob J. Hyndman suggests in his blog post ["Thoughts on the Ljung-Box test"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/).

```
p.values = numeric(2*144)
for (i in 1:(2*144)){
  p.pvalues[i] = Box.test(fit$residuals, lag=(3+1+i), type="Box-Pierce", fitdf=(3+1))$p.value
}
```

$p$-values are greater 0.05 for $h \in (5;80)$ but smaller 0.05 for $h \in(81;288)$.

**Question:** How do the results of the Ljung-Box-Pierce test and the plotted ACF match?

I thought most test results should have a $p$-value greater than 0.05 as I saw the ACF. Maybe something is wrong with the degrees of freedom, because of the 91 estimated coefficients in the `xreg` argument?

I'm sorry, but I'm not allowed to publish data.

**EDIT :**

As advised by @RichardHardy I perform a Breusch-Godfrey-Test in addition to the Ljung-Box-Pierce-Test and create plots showing the p-values to their corresponding lags. You can see, for small lags the Ljung-Box-Pierce test favors the null hypothesis, because of its biased estimation. But essentially both tests converge against a p-value of null for very high lags, eventhough the calculated serial correlation is not higher as in smaller lags.

[image: p-values for serial correlation tests with high lag]

```
 p.values.bgtest = numeric(2*144)
 for (i in 1:(2*144)){
   p.values.bgtest[i] = bgtest(fit$residuals ~ 1, order=i)$p.value
 }
```

Comment: You can find suggestions for $h$ by Hyndman on http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/

Comment: You cannot apply the Ljung-Box test on residuals of an ARMA model; see e.g. ["Testing for autocorrelation: Ljung-Box versus Breusch-Godfrey"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/testing-for-autocorrelation-ljung-box-versus-breusch-godfrey) or ["How many lags to use in the Ljung-Box test of a time series?"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/how-many-lags-to-use-in-the-ljung-box-test-of-a-time-series/205262#205262).

Comment: @RichardHardy so you think a B-G-test should do the work?  In fact I don't understand my results, because the distortion of the Q-statistic favors the null hypothesis. In my mind, that doesn't explain why the p-values are so small for great lags.

Comment: Beats me, I don't know why this is happening...

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for answering as well. Furthermore, the B-G-test provides the same results for a lag over 80.