# Using Ljung-Box Test vs Breusch-Godfrey test in MA/ARIMA models

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive, moving-average

I am learning about residual diagnostics for MA/ARIMA models. I have learnt from the following [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/testing-for-autocorrelation-ljung-box-versus-breusch-godfrey) that the Ljung-Box test cannot be used for models with lagged components of the dependent variable (i.e. when there is weak exogeneity in the model). It is preferred to use the Breusch-Godfrey test in this case. But, I am confused with the usage of Breusch-Godfrey test when there is simply MA components or a combination of both, i.e., ARIMA models.

1. Would the auxiliary equation be like: $w_t = \alpha_0 + ( \sum_{i=1}^{k} \alpha_i y_{t-i} ) + ( \sum_{i=1}^{p} \rho_i w_{t-i} ) + e_t$, where $y_{t-i}$ denote the lagged dependent variables. If yes, then I am guessing this will be generic form for ARIMA models (where $k$ would denote the `p` value in `ARIMA(p, q)`) and in case of MA models, $k$ would be `0`. The variable `p` in the auxiliary regression equation would denote the maximum lags for which the test is being performed. Please correct me if this understanding is incorrect.
2. We know that when there are AR terms, Ljung-Box test does not hold good. However, how can we mathematically compare it with Breusch-Godfrey test when there is just the MA terms? Logically, I am thinking both would be equally preferable, but Breusch-Godfrey test would stand-out as it comes with weaker assumptions and does not depend upon absence of autocorrelation to test its presence in the first place, like L-B test. Any good pointers would really be helpful to understand this assumption of mine.

Comment: Related: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500812), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500783), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500808), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512037).